# Floating analog input value

Tags: arduino, esp8266, floating

To use my sensor I need to supply 24V. So I converted 4.5 V from battery pack to 24V and converted it again to 0-1.66V using a voltage divider. So far I can read the output of the sensor using the wifi module ESP 8266. However, the value is slightly floating (~4). Is there any way to eliminate this floating?
[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of 'floating value' ?

Comment: What does the value '4' represent?

Comment: At default position the sensor value is randomly changing between 5~12. I expected it to be steady at one value, since the sensor is not moving.

Comment: Again, what does the value 4 represent? What does 5~12 represent?

Comment: What sensor is it ???

Comment: Analog value between 0-1023. 4 represents an analog value which corresponds to 0.00649071358 V.

Comment: It is an encoder: https://www.sick.com/de/en/encoders/wire-draw-encoders/ecoline/c/g287337

Comment: Note that "floating" usually means a signal is not electrically connected, hence there's no value at all to read. The term you're looking for is "jitter", meaning random fluctuations of the signal.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the sensor's output is noisy. Put a capacitor (100nF or so) at the sensor output to reduce the noise.

Or 
in the coding side, you can take \$N\$ samples of sensor value and then average it. Use this average value for further calculations.

You may also want to calibrate the sensor.

**Calibration**

1. Find the minimum ADC reading given by the sensor - \$S_{min}\$
2. Find the maximum ADC reading as well - \$S_{max}\$
3. Your sensor therefore gives value \$x\$ in range \$(S_{min} - S_{max})\$, which you can map to \$x_m\$ in the range \$(0 - 1023)\$ mathematically in the code using the relation:

$$\frac{x-S_{min}}{S_{max}-S_{min}}=\frac{x_m-0}{1023-0}$$
Use \$x_m\$ for further calculations.

Comment: Tried with a capacitor. Couldnt eliminate the noise. Putting an extra 10K Ohm resistor between A0 and GND helped.